# Strategy Pattern- Correct Implementation

Tags: c#, strategy-pattern

I'm using this pattern for the first time, and using C#.

I just wanted to check that this is the correct implementation.
I have a button on a Winform, and when clicked on that will output some data in a particular format, defined by choosing from a drop down box.  Now this may change in the future, hence me using the Strategy pattern to encapsulate what changes.

I have a 'Strategy Interface' that simply exposes a single method: "Display Data()".

On my button click I use the following code:

```
private void ConfirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IViewData viewData;

        switch (outputMedia)
        {
            case "Excel":
                viewData = new ExcelOutput(operation, study);
                viewData.DisplayData();
                break;
            case "Spotfire":
                viewData = new SpotfireOutput(operation, study);
                viewData.DisplayData();
                break;
        }


    }
```

Is this an acceptable way to use this pattern?  Obviously if additional output media is identified then I will simply create a new subclass and add an extra 'case' on the switch statement.

Thanks.

Comment: this is factory pattern, not the strategy pattern.

Comment: @Mubashir, can you please elaborate as this website http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rmcochran/strategypattern08072006095804am/strategypattern.aspx  claims that what I have done is pretty much the Strategy pattern.  Thanks

Comment: The strategy pattern allows you to change the behaviour of the system depending on what strategy is selected. You're just populating different data. Move the selection of ViewData into a ViewData factory.

Comment: @Massif, I'm not populating different data.  The data is exactly the same, I am just changing the behaviour, eg the display method.

Comment: I see now, I only ever use lambdas as my strategies, a la CodeInChaos's solution. The creation of a new class confused me.

Comment: @Massif, do you have a link to that solution please?  I like to look at different ways to do things.  Thanks.

Comment: Wikipedia's entry used to have an implementation using lambdas: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Strategy_pattern&oldid=395987706#C.23

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to use Strategy would be to separate the creation of the `IViewData` object from its usage. The creation itself might be handled by a Factory Method. Then you can use the created `IViewData` in a separate location, which is totally unaware of the object's concrete class.

E.g.

```
private IViewData CreateViewData()
{
    IViewData viewData;

    switch (outputMedia)
    {
        case "Excel":
            viewData = new ExcelOutput(operation, study);
            break;
        case "Spotfire":
            viewData = new SpotfireOutput(operation, study);
            break;
    }
    return viewData;
}

...

private void ConfirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IViewData viewData = CreateViewData();

    viewData.DisplayData();
}
```

Now, from this, you can improve the solution further by refactoring the Factory Method. You may decide to use a `Dictionary` instead of a `switch`, or to create the view data objects only once and cache them, or (as you suggested) replacing it with dependency injection ...

Comment: Using dependency injection, for example?  I think in my case, that may be a little overkill and difficult to factor in, as this is a button on a winform.  I hope i've understood you correctly.

Comment: Aah okay, I understand now.  I posted my initial comment before you added the code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can move `viewData.DisplayData();` out of the switch. No need to repeat it for each case. And being able to call `DisplayData` in the same way for all of them is the whole point you introduced that interface in the first place.

Passing in the parameters in the same way in every `case` looks a bit repetitive too. So perhaps use a `Dictionary<string,Func<Operation,Study,IViewData>>` instead. But if different classes require different constructors this isn't going to work.

Comment: Hi, I've never seen a Dictionary used with that nomenclature before.  I'm used to the standard <key, value> pair.  Can you explain what this is, if you don't mind.  Thanks.

Comment: `string` is the key and `Func<Operation,Study,IViewData>` is the value. And it happens to be a generic type itself which describes a function mapping parameters of types `Operation` and `Study` to `IViewData`.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the switch statement into its own method, ideally on some controller class.  This means you dont have to re-write the switch code again when you need an IViewData object.

```
private void ConfirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IViewData viewData = ViewDataController.GetViewDataController(outputMedia, operation, study);

   viewData.DisplayData();

}
```

And then in your controller:

```
 public class ViewDataController
 {
    public static IViewData GetViewDataController(string outputMedia, string operation, string study)
    {
      IViewData viewData = null;

      switch (outputMedia)
      {
        case "Excel":
            viewData = new ExcelOutput(operation, study);
            break;
        case "Spotfire":
            viewData = new SpotfireOutput(operation, study);
            break;
      }
      return viewData;
     }
```

This will allow you to reuse the same code throughout your application, and if you ever need to add any entries to the switch statement then you only have to do it in one place.

Comment: But I would still need to re-write the switch statement within the controller, wouldn't I?

Comment: You write the switch in the controller once and then call it whenever you need it using   "IViewData viewData = ViewDataController.GetViewDataController(outputMedia, operation, study);"  
 You dont need to re-write it anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks.  I am actually going to be re-writing some of this code using my newly found knowledge of the MVP pattern (I have gone a little pattern crazy recently) and will incorporate this into that.